# Server side reporting options for Silverlight Viewer

Tags: arcgis-server, software-recommendations, silverlight

I am looking for suggestions from user community regarding some options for complex reporting. I would like to allow users to browse for data and then based on their selection they can generate a preformatted report and download the reprot as PDF. I want to have reporting logic on server so that we can accommodate any future technology changes and be able to use existing development

I have looked at number of third party controls like Infragistics/Comopnent One/Pertpetuum/ Dev Express/Telrik/Active Reports. I am not sure Crystal reports are an option. Most of the third party controls that I have seen are based on client side.

Answer (score 4):

I am a big fan of SQL Server Reporting Services (free with SQL Server 2008) and personally prefer it over Crystal.

Although there is no native support for it with ArcGIS (although promote the [idea here](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008DRuAAM)) I have seen some people integrate the two using Query Layers with v10.

[This forum post](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/8261-SQL-Reporting-Services-and-ArcGIS-Server) has more details and a video, and also some info on how to grab a map image via REST and some server side .NET code.

I also understand that at 10.1, there has been some work on reporting and having it exposed via ArcPy means you will be able to utilise it via a geoprocessing service, meaning no reliance on a 3rd party reporting tool.

I am associated with a product called Dekho, but it does have great reporting functionality built into the product - more info you can check out some blog posts on integrating it with SSRS [here](http://www.dekho.com.au/integrating-dekho-and-sql-server-reporting-services-part-5/).

Answer (score 1):

[Latitude Geographics](http://www.latitudegeo.com/)' product [Geocortex Essentials](http://www.geocortex.com/arcgis-server-software/geocortex-essentials/viewers/) is one option.  You are able to create report templates that can generate a PDF based on what you are looking at ("print templates") or from a selection of data in a viewer ("layer reports").

Reports are generated server-side with the intent that you can replace the viewer with another technology without having to re-create your reports.

Disclaimer: I work at Latitude Geographics, although not directly on the Essentials product.